# Alpine-linux sed command debug mode

Tags: sed, alpine-linux

I am trying to insert the following text into any file. I do it in the following way:

```
sed -i '1i JRE_HOME="${JAVA_HOME}/jre" \
       CATALINA_PID="${CATALINA_HOME}/temp/tomcat.pid" \
       CATALINA_OPTS="-XX:+PrintCodeCache -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xms512m -Xmx1024m" \
       JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=${TZ} -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"' ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/setenv.sh
```

but when I execute the sed command the file is empty and I don't get any error output or anything that indicates a problem. I see this by running 'echo $?' which prints 0.

Is there a way to run the sed command on Alpine-linux in debug mode?

I also tried "set -x" and got no errors in the output.

Comment: Does the file that you're editing exist and does it contain at least one line?

Comment: @Kusalananda the file exists, I have created it with the 'touch' command, but it is empty. I tried just creating the file and then adding a line at the beginning of the file, that way it works fine. thanks for showing the problem from another perspective. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command might fail without giving any particular error message if the file you're editing is empty.  This was later confirmed to be the case.

If the file is empty, there is no line 1 to insert anything before. Since the line can't be addressed, no insertion is performed.  Failing to find an addressed line is not an error so the exit status will be zero.

Comment: That is precisely the problem, the file is empty, there is no line number one. Thanks for your help.